# Is it possible to have intellisense support in MyGeneration when it comes to write templates?

Tags: c#, .net, code-generation, mygeneration

Is it possible to have intellisense support in MyGeneration when it comes to write templates?

Let's say can I write my templates in Visual Studio and then paste it to MyGeneration template editor somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mygeneration editor does have limited intellisense built into it
[image]

You might be able to create some templates in VS but I'd doubt they would be of much use as any intellisense they did provide wouldn't have the MyGeneration specific features

I can't see exactly what features of VS intellisense that MyGeneration doesnt provide that you would really want.

If you look at T4 which is Microsofts templating language (that isn't supported in MyGeneration afaik) it provides pretty much the same functionality
[image]

Comment: where you having problems getting intellisense working or something?